# Cannot read property of null comparing state after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game.

I want to increment wins after player has selected their option.

I get an error as if the `if` statement is unaware of any value.

Heres the code:

What the state looks like

```js
 const [wins, setWins] = useState(0);
  const [playerSelect, setPlayerSelect] = useState(null);
  const [computerSelect, setComputerSelect] = useState(null);

  // in browser
  {id: 1, name:'rock'}
```

Player select function

```js
  const handleSelection = choice => {
    const optionClicked = options.find(o => o.id === choice);

    setPlayerSelect(optionClicked);

    if (playerSelect.name === 'rock' && computerSelect.name === 'scissors') {
      setWins(wins => wins + 1);
    }
  };
```

I have tried added precautions to check that playerSelect state contains a value first to no prevail. win state in not incremented.

Example:

```js
 const handleSelection = choice => {
    const optionClicked = options.find(o => o.id === choice);

    setPlayerSelect(optionClicked);

    if (
      playerSelect &&
      playerSelect.name &&
      playerSelect.name === 'rock' &&
      computerSelect.name === 'scissors'
    ) {
      setWins(wins => wins + 1);
    }
  };
```

Edit: I have tried the following code and it works after the **second** click only.

```js
const checkWhoWins = () => {
      if (playerSelect.name === 'rock' && computerSelect.name === 'scissors') {
        setWins(wins => wins + 1);
      }
    };
    playerSelect && checkWhoWins();
```

Comment: setState is async, thus playerSelect is an outdated state at if statement

Comment: Ok i understand. How would be the best way to overcome this then? Adding a timer or something seems a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do an action after a state update you would use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for that, and specify its dependencies as second argument:

```
useEffect(() => {
      // you can use optional chaining to avoid triggering errors here
      if (playerSelect?.name === 'rock' && computerSelect?.name === 'scissors') {
        setWins(wins => wins + 1);
      }
}, [playerSelect, computerSelect]) 
   // playerSelect & computerSelect are the correct dependencies here
```